# Can we determine which algorithm runs faster just by looking at their asymptomatic rate?

Tags: computational-complexity

Ok so lets say that the asymptotic execution time of an algorithm B is greater than the asymptotic execution time of an algorithm A .

Τ(Ν)Β = c1*f(N)B > Τ(Ν)A = C2*f(N)A  for c1 and c2 that make the equals statement true

Can we say that as n(input) increases , A will run faster than B?

I'm new here , so forgive me if I got the tags wrong, thanks for your time!

Comment: "asymptomatic" refer to some illness, because it means "without symptom(s)" ; you probably mean "asymptotic."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the execution time of $A$ is asymptotically smaller than $B$, it means that for **sufficiently large** input size $n$, $A$ is faster than $B$. More rigorously, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that, for **all** input size $n\geq N$, $A$ runs faster than $B$.

Comment: What if f(n)A and f(n)B are fixed functions  and they both have execution times of 0(1) ?

Comment: If both algorithms have execution time $O(1)$, then neither is asymptotically faster than the other.

Comment: In these problems the running times are only specified up to a multiplicative constant, so the two have to be different functions to say one is larger.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!